# Robot Framework: How to redirect console output to file

Tags: python, robotframework

I was wondering if it was possible to redirect Robot Framework's stdout from console to file? Currently, when I run pybot, the output is in the command prompt (for Windows), can I change it in such a way that it will go to a file instead? (Nothing displayed on the command prompt).

Comment: Have you tried the normal way to redirect output? `robot ... > console.txt`?

Comment: Hi Bryan, I think this is what I need, though I haven't tried it yet. My purpose is to display the console output to a log dashboard, similar to what Jenkins is doing in it's console output. Will try this later. Many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you just want to log it to you console (in case of Jenkins):

```
*** Keywords ***
Log To Current Console
    [Arguments]  ${TO_LOG}
    Log To Console  \n\n${TO_LOG}
```

Or sometimes it is nice to check the debug of your robot tests:

```
-b --debugfile file      Debug file written during execution. Not created
                         unless this option is specified.
```

Answer (score 2):

On a linux server you can just pipe the robot commandline to tee

```
robot -d results <test name>.robot  | tee <test name>.out
```

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the suggestion from @Bryan, if you want to redirect your output (xml, log, report) to a particular directory or a file, you can use following options for `pybot` script:

```
-d --outputdir dir       Where to create output files. The default is the
                      directory where tests are run from and the given path
                      is considered relative to that unless it is absolute.
-o --output file         XML output file. Given path, similarly as paths given
                      to --log, --report, --xunit, and --debugfile, is
                      relative to --outputdir unless given as an absolute
                      path. Other output files are created based on XML
                      output files after the test execution and XML outputs
                      can also be further processed with Rebot tool. Can be
                      disabled by giving a special value `NONE`. In this
                      case, also log and report are automatically disabled.
                      Default: output.xml
-l --log file            HTML log file. Can be disabled by giving a special
                      value `NONE`. Default: log.html
                      Examples: `--log mylog.html`, `-l NONE`
-r --report file         HTML report file. Can be disabled with `NONE`
                      similarly as --log. Default: report.html
```

Comment: Hi @Daemon12. Thanks for this. However, I'm already aware that Robot Framework has this. What I wanted was to  capture real-time the console output and display it in a log dashboard (similar to what Jenkins does in its console log.) I think Bryan's comment is what I'm looking for. :-) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you run from code, you can do something like

```
import robot.run
with open("message_out.log", "w") as log_file_out, open("message_err.log", "w") as log_file_err:
    robot.run("test",
               stdout=log_file_out,
               stderr=log_file_err)
```